# Как "устойчиво" прикрепить адрес изображения к "image"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Хочу на одном фрейме прикрепить программно адрес изображения к image и при смене фреймов он никуда не пропал и картинка все время была по моему адресу.

Comment: Эээ... А у вас в разных фреймах **один и тот же** `Image` или всё-таки разные?

Comment: @VladD Не, у меня только один Image только на 1 фрейме, и надо чтобы картинка не забывалось при смене...